# How to print a report for each row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, printing

How do I print a report of a spreadsheet such that row `n` is all printed on a single page.  That is, row 1 is on page 1, row 2 is on page 2, etc.

The issue is that some columns have large amounts of text.  Like:

[image: report]

By "report" what I mean is that each record of the database, reflected here as a single row, prints or displays each field on a single page.  For a flat table or spreadsheet this would mean that columns are displayed as rows.  With the proviso that each record (row) displays or prints on a seperate page.

When inputting data into Google forms, it often looks similar to:

[image: form]

and, then, when printing **from** Google forms, each record, as entered, can be printed.  Optionally, Google forms also exports to a spreadsheet.

I have a spreadsheet which I want to print as if it were a Google form.  The spreadsheet originated as SpiceWorks tickets and can be imported to a database as a flat table.

(Looking to use Google sheets rather than a database or report generator.  I'm sure Crystal Reports would accomplish the task, but that would be overkill.)

Comment: what do you mean by "print a report" ?

Comment: I updated the question.  You're right, too vague.

Answer (score 1):

to print a row per page you need to change row's heigh by **Resizing row...**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Good.  Leaving open in case there's a report option.